# Determine which process belongs to which window in Linux System Monitor?

Tags: linux, fedora

I have Fedora Linux 13 64bit system. I use System Monitor to check which process is taking how much memory and cpu. Normally I have dozens of Chrome and Firefox windows open. The Processes tab shows which process is taking how much cpu/ram resources but I unfortunately there is no option like right click and make the window active that matches the PID (the one process that I have currently highlighted). Usually there is a chrome process taking up 30 or 40 percent of CPU while dozens other chrome processes taking much less cpu.  I must determine which chrome window ( or any application which has multiple instances running) is taking that much CPU time. So can some one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Try the `xprop` command. After running `xprop`, click on whichever Window you believe is taking up the CPU to find out it's PID.

To narrow down the information it spits out, try:

```
xprop _NET_WM_PID
```

to get the PID specifically.